# Centering my css3 menu of changing widths...?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a css menu which has a width of 400 for non-Admins... and a width of 500 for Admins. If I set the UL width to 500, the menu centers fine and nicely for Admins.  But for non-admins, whose mneu is really only 400 wide... it's off-kilter.

So I removed the width attribute from the UL to try and remove this and then it lost centering altogether; the whole menu is now stuck to the left side of the container.

Anyone have a simple idea for how to make it always centered?  Site is here:
http://www.runic-paradise.com/

```
ul.menu{
    height: 40px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*width: 500px;*/
}

/*li{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    color:#191919;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}*/

a.menu{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

p.menu{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

    .subtext{
    padding-top: 10px;

    }

ul.menu li{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    color: #191919;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Menu Color Classes*/
.green{
    background:#6AA63B url('/img/menu/green-item-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}    
.yellow{
    background:#FBC700 url('/img/menu/yellow-item-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}    
.red{
    background:#D52100 url('/img/menu/red-item-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}    
.purple{
    background:#5122B4 url('/img/menu/purple-item-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}    
.blue{
    background:#0292C0 url('/img/menu/blue-item-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}





<ul class="menu">
    <li class="green">
        <p class="menu"><a href="/" class="menu">Home</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">The front page</p>
    </li>
    <li class="yellow">
        <p class="menu"><a href="#" class="menu">-</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">More info</p>
    </li>
    <li class="red">
        <p class="menu"><a href="/forums/" class="menu">Forums</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">Get in touch</p>
    </li>
    <li class="blue">
        <p class="menu"><a href="#" class="menu">-</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">Send us your stuff!</p>
    </li>
<?php
if ($user->data['group_id'] == 5)
{
   echo '   <li class="purple">
        <p class="menu"><a href="#" class="menu">Admin</a></p><p class="subtext">Legal things</p>
    </li>';
}

?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS sets the `ul.menu` width to 400px. If the user is admin, the php script adds another 100px wide li to `ul.menu`. When this happens, you have to set the `ul.menu` width to 500px. If you do this, the css rule `margin:0px auto;` will handle the centering as expected.

A simple jQuery fix would be something like **this:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu=$('ul.menu');
    if(menu.find('li')>4) {
        //if there are more then 4 menu items, reset menu width to 500px
        menu.css('width','500px');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've added this to the scripts at the bottom of my page; hwvr its setting UL width to 500 even if the purple LI doesnt exist. Maybe I should give the li.purple an ID and try to find it that way? how might that change the code tho? :-x

Comment: @runelynx Oh, sorry! my bad. Just change the if condition to `menu.find('li.purple')>0` instead of just `menu.find('li.purple')`.

Comment: still no dice :(  did some research and changed it to this... and now it works. I guess I just cant use LI's anywhere else on the page though or it'll mess up the count? :)

<script>

    if($(" li ").length>4) {
        menu.css('width','500px');
    }

Comment: ah ha!! even better :)  give the UL an ID of adminmenu, then can find LIs just within that

 
    if($("#adminmenu li").length>4)

Comment: @runelynx There you go. However, doing `if(menu.find('li').length>4)` will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width:500px;`for UL.Demo for these http://jsfiddle.net/dhanith/ZMB93/

Comment: this leaves the same problem unfortunately :(  it's still shifted to the left, leaving space for the missing Admin LI menu item

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you please try this,

In animated-menu.css (demo url: http://www.runic-paradise.com/), Change margin style as like below

```
ul.menu {
  height: 40px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: auto 25%;
}
```

Comment: Have updated... but it's cutting the 5th LI item down onto a new line now

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. Here seems fine.

Comment: @ChinnuR No, there is no point setting the top, bottom margins to auto. Also, the left and right margins should be set to auto as it is done in the first place.